# No route matches [GET] "/user/1" following Michael Hartls rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am on listing [7.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#top), and am getting a no route error. I am very new to rails, so what other files can I provide to help debug by no route.

Here is my routes files

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'


end
```

Comment: Check out rake routes in your terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "/users/1", not "/user/1".

Comment: Yes, it is just how Rails does routing.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem )

My mistake was `resource :users` in routes.rb

But correct is `resources :users`

In first case you get `GET    /users(.:format)      users#show` rake route output and can access your user throo url `http://localhost:3000/users?id=1`

In second case you get `user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show` rake route output and can access your user throo url `http://localhost:3000/users/1`